# How to delete a specific value in a cookie array Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-8

I'm trying to delete a specific value from the cookie array called 'wishlist'. I tried using `Cookie::forget('wishlist');`. I'm using a destroy method in the controller.

The problem is that it deletes the *entire* cookie array and not just the specified value.

destroy()

```php
    public function destroy($id)
    {

        $books = Book::findOrFail($id);

        $cookie = Cookie::get('wishlist');
        $cookieArray = explode(',', json_decode($cookie));
        $flattenedArray = Arr::flatten($cookieArray);

        $arrayId = array_search($id, $flattenedArray);

        unset($flattenedArray[$arrayId]);

        $cookie = Cookie::forget('wishlist');


        return redirect()->route('wishlist.index', ['books' => $books])->withCookie($cookie);
    }
```

Comment: you can set a new empty or null wishlist cookie, so it also removes it.

Comment: I only want a specific value removed from the cookie array. I want the same cookie without the specified value in the array

Comment: I would think you just re-set the cookie with the new value

Answer (score 0):

Cookies don't accept an array, so you have to store the string in the cookie and explode on every usage and implode after any changes to store in the cookie
To resolve your problem you have to search and find the index of a value that you are looking for and then use unset() function to remove that index.